# How to read JSON data in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I have a Server 1 which will post JSON data to my Server 2 URL (Drupal Site)

Sample JSON Request Object

```
{"ConfirmationNumber":"344", "E-mailAddress":"EMAIL@ADDRESS.COM", "FirstName":"FIRSTNAME", "LastName":"LASTNAME", "SKU":"XYZ"}
```

I need to read the above request in Drupal site means Server 2 to parse the JSON Object and to do some business logic. Any quick help is really appreciated

Example:
http://mydrupalsite.com/services/register

Some external site is posting the JSON data to my above URL.

I need to read the JSON Content they posted in my drupal site. This is what I want. Getting/Reading the data is the my first step. Parsing is fine which we can do as next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_services_resources().
 */
function yourmodulename_services_resources() {
  return array(
   'yourmodulename' => array(
     'create' => array(
       'help' => 'Retrievs a test',
       'callback' => '_yourmodulename_create',
       'access callback' => '_yourmodulename_access',      
       'args' => array(
         array(
            'name' => 'data',
            'type' => 'struct',
            'description' => 'The note object',
            'source' => 'data',
            'optional' => FALSE, 
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ),
  );
}

/**
 * Callback for creating  resources.
 *
 * @param object $data
 * @return object
 */
function _yourmodulename_create($data) {
return $data;
}

/**
 * Access callback for the note resource.
 *
 * @param string $op
 *  The operation that's going to be performed.
 * @param array $args
 *  The arguments that will be passed to the callback.
 * @return bool
 *  Whether access is given or not.
 */
function _yourmodulename_access($op, $args) {
  $access = TRUE;
  return $access;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To read json response.

```
$url = "your request url";
$request = drupal_http_request($url);
$json_response = drupal_json_decode($request->data);
foreach ($json_response as $response_data) {
  //your operation code  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use drupal_json_encode: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_decode/7

Regards.

Comment: As I am new to drupal. Can you provide the syntax for it. Thanks for your quick response. Bascially I not looking for parsing JSON in drupal. Instead I want to know how we can read the JSON data posted to our URL in drupal.

Comment: Mario: I update the question please check my example in order to get what I want. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Use drupal_json_decode($data). You will get a php array. Then use foreach and loop through it to fetch values.

```
$content = drupal_json_decode($data);
foreach($content as $key => $value) {
  // here $value will contain your value. You can perform any business logic with     $value...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If need take JSON object from url, for example {"text":"HelloWorld"}. I advise you to use this method:

```
//Create a path
$mypath = 'http://example.com';
//Create a option
$options = array('query' => array('parametr1' => '1', 'parametr2' => '2'));
//Create url
$url = url($path = $url, $options);
//Create request 
$request = drupal_http_request($url);
//Take response data(A string containing the response body that was received)
$json_response = drupal_json_decode($request->data);
// Varible text return HelloWorld 
$text = $json_response['text'];
```

Regards